# Search with Array of values Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ransack

I'm working with ransack and using its form like

```
 <%= search_form_for @search, url: box_index_admin_medleys_path do |f| %>
   <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
     <div class="form-group">
       <%= f.label :name_cont, Spree.t(:name) %>
       <%= f.text_field :name_cont, size: 15, class: "form-control" %>
     </div>
   </div>
 <% end %>
```

now I want to merge an array of values in params[:q]

like

> Model.where(id: [1,2,3,4]).ransack(params[:q])
> and want to apply search only on those records whose ids are in the array.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49370841/search-an-array-of-values-with-ransack

Comment: @MayureshSrivastava not defined pretty well that how can we use it or merge it